# Write a program that takes in a input and reverse the users output?

Tags: python, input, output, reverse

The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Hello there
Hey
done
```

then the output is:

```
ereht olleH
yeH
```

I have written most the program but I'm struggling with defining the `user_string`.

```
user_string = str(input())

while True:
    user_string = str(input())
    if user_string == 'Done' or mystring == 'done' or mystring == 'd':
        break
    print(user_string[::-1])
```

Comment: What's `mystring`? I guess you mean `if user_string in ('done', 'Done', 'd'):` and also, `input` already returns a string, so `str()` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `mystring` is supposed to do, as it just suddenly appears without any clear purpose.

However making judgement from the given code you should try:

```
# this line seems redundant, remove it. --> user_string = str(input())

while True:
    user_string = input() # str() not needed as input() returns a String by default.
    if user_string.lower() in {'done', 'd'}:
        break
    print(user_string[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In you if condition you have to compare user_string with Done, d or done instead of the variable `mystring` . Here is how it should be

```
#user_string = str(input()) you do not need this 

while True:
    user_string = str(input())
    if user_string == 'Done' or user_string == 'done' or user_string == 'd':
        break
    print(user_string[::-1])
```

Comment: It gives me a EOFError